# Detect click outside divs with particular class and hide them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My DOM looks like this:

```
<div class = filter x>
    <div class = a>
        <ul><li>……..</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = filter y>
    <div class = a>
        <ul><li>……..</li></ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Both the divs with class a are dropdown menus. The expected functionality is:

1. Whenever I click on divs with class filter, js-active class is added
   and the dropdown opens.
2. Whenever I click anywhere outside the div or
   the dropdown, js-active class is removed and the dropdown hides.
3. At a time, only one out of the two dropdowns will be open.

Another event that I am handling is that if one dropdown is visible and I click on another dropdown, first one hides (remove class js-active)

I am able to achieve this with the following code:

```
 $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(e){
       var xContainer = $(‘.filter x’);
       var yContainer = $(‘.filter y’);
       if (!xContainer.is(e.target) && xContainer.has(e.target).length === 0)
          {
              xContainer.removeClass('js-active');
          }
       if (!yContainer.is(e.target) && yContainer.has(e.target).length === 0)
          {
              yContainer.removeClass('js-active');
          }
 });
```

I want to optimize this code. I tried using jQuery "each" to iterate over all the divs with class filter and use the same logic but it didn’t work as expected. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y3br116y/1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying more, I got this to work too:

```
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(e){
            $('.filter').each(function(){
                if(!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('js-active');
                }
            });
        });
```

Works on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to handle both x & y separately, you can do something like

```js
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
  var $filter = $(e.target).closest('.filter');
  if ($filter.length) {
    $filter.addClass('active');
  }
  $('.filter.active').not($filter).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.filter {
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.filter .a {
  display: none;
}
.filter.active .a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter x">
  <div class="a">
    <ul>
      <li>……..</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter y">
  <div class="a">
    <ul>
      <li>……..</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
Some other content
```

Comment: Thank you. Please look at my comment too and suggest if there is anything wrong with that approach.

Comment: @ayushi which comment

Comment: My answer, right below yours. It works functionality wise but I just wanted to know if there is anything wrong with the approach I have taken.